# use objective-C native custom framework/code in phone gap

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

I have a framework in Objective-C
working fine with iPhone apps.

My query is that can i use the same framework in my [phone gap](http://phonegap.com) code for hybrid?

How can i do that?

Is i need to [create plugin for it](http://blog.instabug.com/2015/09/using-native-libraries-in-phonegap-a-diy-guide/)?

or add something like this

```
<framework src=“custom.framework”/>
```

[Create Custom Framework tutorial](http://insert.io/frameworkios8xcode6/)

Comment: I think you have enough information on your "create plugin for it" link

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to create a plugin to wrap the native framework and provide a JS API to the Cordova app to make use of it.

You'll indeed need to add a [`<framework>`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.0.0/plugin_ref/spec.html#framework-element) element to the plugin.xml to create a reference in the Xcode project generated by Cordova.

You'll need to create an Objective-C class that implements the plugin interface with methods that wrap the framework API and a JS interface which calls the methods in the native class.

Note that only string parameters can be passed between the JS-Objective C interface, so if you need to send non-trivial data types (e.g. objects/arrays) across the interface, this is best done using stringified JSON structures.

[pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin) is an example of a Cordova plugin that wraps a native framework - take a look at the source code for an idea how to implement such a plugin.